# Selenium Webdriver hangs/freezes when switching to an alert

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

Been using selenium in python and I get an alert when I load a URL. When I switch to the alert the first time it handles it fine. When visiting another URL on the same website, the Webdriver hangs/freezes when switching to the same alert alert.

This is what I'm trying currently:

```
          try:
               sleep(1)
               while EC.alert_is_present():
                    sleep(3)
                    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.alert_is_present())
                    alert = driver.switch_to.alert
                    alert.accept()
                    break

          except:
               pass
```

When debugging, it seems Webdriver hangs/freezes the second time around on: WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.alert_is_present())

I've tried running it like this and still get the same issue:

```
          try:
               sleep(1)
               while EC.alert_is_present():
                    sleep(3)
                    alert = driver.switch_to.alert
                    alert.accept()
                    break

          except:
               pass
```

This time it hangs/freezes on: alert = driver.switch_to.alert

Have tried it with and without the sleep() and have tried using WebDriverWait(), all combinations of those and still no luck.